# I need to add custom Order Item attribute and Quote Item attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, sales-order, custom-attributes, quoteitem

I need to add custom order item attribute and quote item attribute at when product add to cart. Attribute value store in quote item table but not in order item table.

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <DD_Customoption>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </DD_Customoption>
  </modules>
  <global>
      <fieldsets>
             <sales_convert_quote>
                   <result_image>
                       <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
                    </result_image>
            </sales_convert_quote>               
       </fieldsets>
    <helpers>
      <customoption>
        <class>DD_Customoption_Helper</class>
      </customoption>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <customoption>
        <class>DD_Customoption_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>customoption_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </customoption>
    </models>
    <events>
      <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>customoption/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>updateOptions</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add_handler>
        </observers>
      </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

**Observer.php**

```
public function updateOptions(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

        $params = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();


        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEditValue(serialize($params));

        $headStoneValue = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getImageDivValue();
        $html = $params['result_image'];

        $headStoneValue = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getHeadStoneValue();
        $headStone = unserialize($headStoneValue);
        $quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item');
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        $product_id = $headStone['productId'];
        $stoneType = $headStone['stoneType'];



        $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);


        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
        $cart->init();


        $options = array();

        if (!empty($headStone['stoneType'])) {
            $stoneType = $headStone['stoneType'];
            $options[7] = $stoneType;
        }

        if (!empty($headStone['stoneSize'])) {
            $stoneSize = $headStone['stoneSize'];
            $options[6] = $stoneSize;
        }


        if (!empty($headStone['pannelName'])) {
            $pannelName = $headStone['pannelName'];
            $options[3] = $pannelName;
        }

        if (!empty($headStone['colorName'])) {
            $colorName = $headStone['colorName'];
            $options[5] = $colorName;
        }


        if (!empty($params['name'])) {
            $name = $params['name'];
            $options[11] = $name;
        }

        if (!empty($params['bod'])) {
            $bod = $params['bod'];
            $options[10] = $bod;
        }

        if (!empty($params['expire-date'])) {
            $expire = $params['expire-date'];
            $options[9] = $expire;
        }

        if (!empty($params['result-about'])) {
            $aboutResult = $params['result-about'];
            $options[8] = $aboutResult;
        }


        $cart->addProduct($productCollection, array('product_id' => $product_id,
            'qty' => 1,
            'options' => $options
        ));
        $cart->save();

        $items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();



        foreach ($items as $item) {

            $product = $item->getProduct();
            $productIds = $product->getEntityId();
            if ($productIds == $product_id) {
                $item->setCustomPrice($params['finalPrice']);
                $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($params['finalPrice']);
                $item->setResultImage($html);
                $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                $item->save();
            }
        }


        /* add Result data */

        $resultModel = Mage::getModel('headstone/stoneresult');



    }
```

Comment: Did you tried this?  <sales_convert_quote_item>
                <result_image>
                    <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
                </result_image>

Answer (score 0):

In order to save some additional details in quote items table, you need to first create a new column in `sales_flat_quote_item` table. Then only your save action will work.

Magento Sales Quotes and Sales Orders are not EAV entities. They are flat entities.